# c# WPF 'The name xxx does not exist in the namespace - what am i missing?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to learn WPF, and specifically, understand data-binding. I have started to run through some examples online. I cannot get [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-simple-binding#example) one to work. I have created a Simple Person object as follows and it is in the correct namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace SimpleDataBinding
    {
        public class Person
        {
            private string name;
            public Person()
            {
            }
            public Person(string value)
            {
                this.name = value;
            }
            public string PersonName
            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created an object of this type.

```
namespace SimpleDataBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Person Person = new Person();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

and the XAML is as follows - the last line shows the line that it fails on.

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:SimpleDataBinding"
  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
  Title="Simple Data Binding Sample">

    <Window.Resources>
        <src:Person x:Key="myDataSource" PersonName="Joe"/>
```

The error from the build is.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The name "Person" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SimpleDataBinding".    SimpleDataBinding   ...\repos\SimpleDataBinding\SimpleDataBinding\MainWindow.xaml

But, Person does exist, and is in the shared namespace. Looking around here at similar issues all i get are recommendations to rebuild, or clean and rebuild - none of which seem to help anyone (or me).

As i'm new to this, it's likely, i just don't understand something and it's super-frustrating as i should surely be able to get this to work!

I've pushed the project to github [here](https://github.com/ssmith73/SimpleDataBinding) if it helps anyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the [x:Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-class-directive) directive on your window definition.  Update your window element in the XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="SimpleDataBinding.MainWindow"
    ....
```